# Id requests and their generic titles

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, asking-questions

I apologise in advance for formatting and orthography errors that may appear here, as I am currently on mobile.

Just right now I saw a [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) with the awesome title of: ["Looking for the name of an anime"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/looking-for-the-name-of-an-anime)

As some of you may know, the SE network does [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) not allow duplicate titles for questions. This can be circumvented by adding additional whitespaces to the title, but that is not the issue.

What is more problematic IMO is the fact that the title is completely search-resistant, generic and totally uninteresting.

On a different site, where I am also active, the editing of titles by avid members and moderators is actively promoted. Should that also happen here, especially with ID requests, where a catchy title is the key to getting interested and knowledgeable users to read and answer the question? And how can we encourage especially new users to formulate catchy titles?

Comment: Related: [Should there be a Guide line for naming Identification requests?](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/889/should-there-be-a-guide-line-for-naming-identification-requests)

Comment: Maybe just compile together any descriptive terms like "Girl in red takes sword out of stone" and such?